# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/times.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c, windows, git, visual-studio

i am trying to compile a build.sh file using visual studio, but i get this error.

> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Engineer\Anaconda;.;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Engineer\Anaconda3\Scripts;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Engineer\Anaconda3;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Engineer\Anaconda3\Scripts;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Users\Engineer\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\CTEX\UserData\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files\Python36;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;%C;C:\Program Files\Git\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
>   Set INCLUDE = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include;
>   Set LIB = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\lib\win64;
>   Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\Lib\amd64;
>
> ### Options file details

```
Compiler location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\..\
Options file: C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2018b\mex_C++_win64.xml
CMDLINE200 : link /nologo /manifest  /DLL  /EXPORT:mexFunction /EXPORT:mexfilerequiredapiversion C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\csa.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\kofn.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\match.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Exception.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Matrix.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Random.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\String.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Timer.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\cpp_mexapi_version.obj  /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib libMatlabDataArray.lib libMatlabEngine.lib /out:correspondPixels.mexw64
CMDLINE250 : mt -outputresource:correspondPixels.mexw64;2 -manifest "correspondPixels.mexw64.manifest"
CMDLINE300 : del "correspondPixels.exp" "correspondPixels.lib" "correspondPixels.mexw64.manifest" "correspondPixels.ilk"
COMPILER : cl
COMPFLAGS : /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD
COMPDEFINES : /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
MATLABMEX :  /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
OPTIMFLAGS : /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG
INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include"
DEBUGFLAGS : /Z7
LINKER : link
LINKFLAGS : /nologo /manifest 
LINKTYPE : /DLL
LINKEXPORT : /EXPORT:mexFunction
LINKEXPORTVER : /EXPORT:mexFunction /EXPORT:mexfilerequiredapiversion
LINKLIBS : /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib libMatlabDataArray.lib libMatlabEngine.lib
LINKDEBUGFLAGS : /debug /PDB:"correspondPixels.mexw64.pdb"
LINKOPTIMFLAGS : 
OBJEXT : .obj
LDEXT : .mexw64
SETENV : set COMPILER=cl
            set COMPFLAGS=/c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
            set OPTIMFLAGS=/O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG
            set DEBUGFLAGS=/Z7
            set LINKER=link
            set LINKFLAGS=/nologo /manifest  /export:%ENTRYPOINT% /DLL /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib libMatlabDataArray.lib libMatlabEngine.lib /EXPORT:mexFunction
            set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=/debug /PDB:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%.mexw64.pdb"
            set NAME_OUTPUT=/out:"%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
VCROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
SDKROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
VSINSTALLDIR : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
VCINSTALLDIR : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\
VCVARSALLDIR : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
KITSROOT : C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
SDKVERSION : 10.0.10240.0
MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b
ARCH : win64
SRC : "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\correspondPixels.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\csa.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\kofn.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\match.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Exception.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Matrix.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Random.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\String.cc";"D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Timer.cc";"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
OBJ : C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\csa.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\kofn.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\match.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Exception.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Matrix.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Random.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\String.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Timer.obj;C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
OBJS : C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\csa.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\kofn.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\match.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Exception.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Matrix.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Random.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\String.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Timer.obj C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\cpp_mexapi_version.obj 
SRCROOT : D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\correspondPixels
DEF : C:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.def
EXP : "correspondPixels.exp"
LIB : "correspondPixels.lib"
EXE : correspondPixels.mexw64
ILK : "correspondPixels.ilk"
MANIFEST : "correspondPixels.mexw64.manifest"
TEMPNAME : correspondPixels
EXEDIR : 
EXENAME : correspondPixels
CXXFLAGS : \ -O3 -DNOBLAS
OPTIM : /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG
LINKOPTIM : 
CMDLINE100_0 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\correspondPixels.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.obj
CMDLINE100_1 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\csa.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\csa.obj
CMDLINE100_2 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\kofn.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\kofn.obj
CMDLINE100_3 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\match.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\match.obj
CMDLINE100_4 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Exception.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Exception.obj
CMDLINE100_5 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Matrix.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Matrix.obj
CMDLINE100_6 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Random.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Random.obj
CMDLINE100_7 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\String.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\String.obj
CMDLINE100_8 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\Timer.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\Timer.obj
```

### CMDLINE100_9 : cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\cpp_mexapi_version.obj

Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015'.
cl /c /Zp8 /GR /W3 /EHs /nologo /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  /DUSE_MEX_CMD   /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_SECURE_SCL=0   /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\simulink\include" "D:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\correspondPixels.cc" /FoC:\Users\Engineer\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_3811659388890865_24300\correspondPixels.obj
Error using mex
correspondPixels.cc
d:\image-segmentation-codes\extended-berkeley-segmentation-benchmark\source\csa.hh(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
'sys/times.h': No such file or directory

Comment: it looks like build.sh is used to be executed on a linux system, cygwin,... 
Unfortunately, there is no sys\time.h header file in MSVC. Instead, try one of the following links for some help coding this on Windows.

(stackoverflow.com/questions/1676036)

(stackoverflow.com/questions/2494356)

Comment: Ouch on the formatting, but thank you for not trying to include an image.  The `<sys/times.h>` header is standard on POSIX-like systems.  Windows doesn't necessarily count as POSIX-like — you might need to install the POSIX support software, or something. If the header is missing, there is a problem on the machine with a pre-requisite missing.  Different headers on different machines is part of the C programming proces — there isn't a `<windows.h>` on Unix machines, for example.  Or get a Unix-like environment on your Windows machine; I usually use Cygwin when I code on Windows.